# rails devise after first sign in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is there a way for us to configure devise to go to a specific page after sign up? Something like `after_sign_up_path` for. I want the users to update their profile on first login after signup, so want to redirect them to `edit_user_path(current_user)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Below is how i implemented it.

```ruby
scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(user)
sign_in(scope, user, {})
redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you know it already
But there is a `after_sign_up_path_for` method which you could override now
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L98